# dreamfactory php script post.post_process payload modify

Tags: php, payload, dreamfactory

Hi I'm using Dreamfactory as REST API backend and I need a PHP script to pre process a POST api request that can modify my received payload from this:

{“Time”:“2018-12-21T07:49:23”,“BME680”:{“Temperature”:20.3,“Humidity”:41.8,“Pressure”:1021.1,“Gas”:286.65}

to this:

{“Time”:“2018-12-21T07:49:23”,“Temperature”:20.3,“Humidity”:41.8,“Pressure”:1021.1,“Gas”:286.65}

How can I acive this with a PHP script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's define a helper function which makes the result friendly

```
function getFriendlyResult(k, input) {
    var output = {};
    for (var key in input) {
        if (key !== k) output[key] = input[key];
    }
    for (var innerKey in input[k]) output[innerKey] = input[innerKey];
    return output;
}
```

and you can call it like:

```
getFriendlyResult(“BME680”, {“Time”:“2018-12-21T07:49:23”,“BME680”:{“Temperature”:20.3,“Humidity”:41.8,“Pressure”:1021.1,“Gas”:286.65});
```

EDIT

To achieve this in PHP, you can call [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and pass your JSON, like

```
$resultArray = json_decode($input, true);
```

and then implement the same algorithm in PHP as I described above in Javascript.

EDIT

This is an untested implementation in PHP:

```
function getFriendlyResult($k, $input) {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
        if ($key !== $k) $output[$key] = $value;
    }
    foreach ($input[$k] as $innerKey => $innerValue) {
        $output[$innerKey] = $innerValue;
    }
    return $output;
}

$result = json_decode($yourJSON, true);
```

Comment: sorry I'm wrong I need script  in php languge not in java. java is not supported in dreamfactory

Comment: Please could you rewrite the script in php I'm newbie in this language. thk

Comment: @LucaFolin I have implemented this in PHP as well for you. Given the fact that I answered your question in two different languages, you might consider accepting this answer.